# Power Automate error when trying to add an attachment array from plumsail

Tags: attachment, power-automate

I have a Plumsail form where a user can attach several pdf or word documents. In power automate I create an array of these documents and then attach the array to the "Start and wait for approval" action. When I run it, I get the error below:

> The request failed. Error code: 'InvalidRequestContent'. Error
> Message: 'The request content was invalid and could not be
> deserialized: 'Could not find member 'ContentBytes' on object of type
> 'ApprovalsConnectorAttachment'.

Comment: Can you show us the JSON from the response that you were working with to get that error?  Also show us the expression that cause this error.  It's hard to help without any of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you followed the [How to send an email from Plumsail form with Power Automate](https://plumsail.com/docs/forms-web/how-to/email.html) Plumsail guide as it tells you to assign the HTTP GET file response to a property named `ContentBytes`.

While this will work with the `Send an Email (V2)` action (from the guide) the `Start and wait for an approval` action expects a property named content `content`.

To fix the problem append the following object to the array (note the `content`property):

```
{
  "name": @{items('Apply_to_each_2')?['file']},
  "content": @{body('HTTP')}
}
```

or as an image:
[image]

Comment: I have the append to an array set up exactly as your sample and I tested to see if it would work using Send Email and it does. But I still get the error on Start and wait for approval.

Comment: Could you post the append to array settings to the question please?